# Connect pyspark Docker container to Visual Studio Code

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, docker-machine

I am new to docker and pyspark and I have pulled imaged from
https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/pyspark-notebook.

Now I want to develop pyspark code using visual studio code. How do I connect these two and where should I place my pyspark code ?

Thanks,
Xi

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this repository where we have a docker image configuration that we use in VScode. Perhaps it can help you along:
https://github.com/Energinet-DataHub/geh-timeseries

Comment: Thank you, I have seen this GitHub, Can you point me where I should change to connect to Visual studio Code. As I am not getting where to do it. Kindly help